# Error on refresh a particuar page in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, node-modules, package.json

Whenever I refresh a particular page ,

> Error: Package subpath './cjs/react.development' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\rites\Desktop\Web Development\next-linkedin\node_modules\react\package.json

the above error occurs. I tried deleting and reinstalling node modules and .lock file but the error still persists.

Now if I use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps even without refreshing it shows the same error.Is there any way to get the rid of this error??